# Create different depth per channel ImageMagick

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, command-line-interface, photo

I've been messing with ImageMagick's `convert` for hours (along with searching the web) and haven't really made any progress. What I want to do is: convert an image into RGBa RAW and change the alpha channel to a depth of 1. I only want the alpha channel to exist for the purpose of a pixel either existing or not with zero partial transparency

eg:
Red: 6 bits
Green: 6 bits
Blue : 6 bits
Alpha: 1 bit

Is this even possible?

Comment: `convert image -channel a -threshold 50% +channel result`

Comment: Thanks but this still seems to use a full 8 bits to store the alpha despite the values being reduced. I might just end up using a mask